# Getting the index of the first occurrence of a given element in a given list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement the following specification:

```
busca.v.xs = <Min i : 0 ≤ i < #xs ∧ xs.i = v : i>
```

I wrote something like the following.

```hs
busca :: Int -> [Int] -> Int

busca v [] = 1000000
busca v (x:xs) | x==v = min x (busca v xs)
               | otherwise = busca v xs
```

When I was deriving, the case `[]` is infinity, so I tried making something that is somewhat similar. The expected result should be the minimun number in a list. For example, `busca 2 [4,3,2,2,7]` should return `2`. Can i use `Maybe` and simulate that infinity in a way?

Comment: That specification is for getting the index of the first occurrence of the element `v` in the list `xs`, not for getting the minimum number in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a fresh type for which `min` did what you ask like this:

```
data PosInfty a = Finite a | Infinite deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

Derived `Ord` instances treat values made with earlier constructors as unconditionally smaller than values made with later constructors, so all `Finite` values will be less than `Infinite`.

This type is also available (with significantly more instances) from [monoid-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.6.1/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html).